# Server / X-Powered-By headers not available in runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, response-headers, api-security

The "Server" and "X-Powered-By" headers are not present in the API response during runtime (or debugging) but appearing only on Postman / browser.
My objective is to remove to Server/powered-by headers but they are not available during runtime for removal. API is based on ASP.NET Core 6.

Screenshot of response headers during runtime:
[image: Headers during runtime]

Screenshot of response headers in Postman

[image]

Comment: Is it only in debug or both?

Comment: Both debug and runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They not appear because these 2 header are added outside runtime as the response go through IIS or IISexpress.
If you publish the app and depoly to IIS, you can remove them by modify the webconfig.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For debugging with IIS express. You can change the related settings in applicationhost.config which loacate at projectfolder-->.vs(hidden)-->config-->applicationhost.config.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://support.waters.com/KB_Inf/Other/WKB202337_How_to_disable_the_X-Powered-By_HTTP_header_in_Microsoft_IIS):

PROCEDURE

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Connect to the local server
3. Select the Default Web
   Site.
   4.Double-click HTTP Response Headers. Select X-Powered-By. Click
   Remove.
4. Click Yes when prompted to confirm the change. For NuGenesis
   versions 9.1+:
5. Repeat steps 4 through 7 for the two sites
   "AuditTrailClientApp" and "AuditTrailWebServer".
6. Click on the local
   server entry.
7. Double-click Configuration Editor. Select the section
   "system.webServer/proxy".
8. Set "arrResponseHeader" to False. Click Apply.
9. Restart the web server.